# Printing a number as a sum of powers of 2 in increasing order

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization

I am trying to print out a decimal integer(non-negative) as sum of powers of 2 i.e for input 10, it should print "2 8" without quotes. I already wrote this code, but can someone give me a one liner for this.

```
n = bin(int(raw_input()))[-1:1:-1]
print (' ').join([str((int(n[j])+1)**j) for j in xrange(len(n)) if n[j] == '1'])
```

Comment: I am not getting, how come 28 from 10??

Comment: its not clear wt you trying here

Comment: OP is trying to get the binary components that make up the integer. So `2+8=10`, `1+2+8=11`, `1+256=257`, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It much better to have this spread across muplitple lines, and using and `input` inside a list comprehension hides a key piece of the information of what your code is doing.

Ultimately, what you are asking to doisn't pretty, but here it is anyway:

```
print (' ').join([str(2**i) for i,j in enumerate(bin(int(raw_input()))[-1:1:-1]) if j == '1'])
```

Pretty printed it is:

```
print ' '.join(
    [str(2**i)
     for i,j in enumerate(
         bin(int(raw_input()))[-1:1:-1]
       )
      if j == '1']
  )
```

Notes:

- `int(n[j])+1)` will always be 2, since you are only iterating if `j` is 1.
- `enumerate` returns a list of tuples each containing the index and value, so you don't need to store `n`, and can test against `j` directly.
- Python can iterate over a list of items without having to fetch them by index, its the difference between `[list[i]**2 for i in len(list)]` and `[i**2 for i in list]`
- You don't need to put brackets around the string, so you can save some space by doing this:

  ```
  " ".join(...)
  ```

  Instead of this:

  ```
  (" ").join(...)
  ```

Comment: you can make that a generator expression instead of list comprehension