# What is the fastest way to represent number as the sum of powers of two in python

Tags: python, binary, numbers

For example

```
>>> two_powers(42)
>>> (2, 8, 32)
```

My current naive implementation (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27936818/1177288)) looks like that

```
def two_powers(num):
    return tuple(2 ** i for i, j in enumerate(bin(num)[-1: 1: -1]) if j == '1')
```

But I hope there're faster ways to do this.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Agile_Eagle I think it's not appropriate for codegolf, as the question is not a puzzle. I need this function to run in a production code. The main criterion is not a quality or beauty or shortness of code, but the performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I decompose a number into powers of 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226094/how-do-i-decompose-a-number-into-powers-of-2)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
def two_powers(num):
    powers = []
    while num != 0:
        powers.append(num & -num)
        num = num & (num - 1)
    return powers
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import math

def two_powers(num):
    # Compute number of bits for big numbers
    num_bits = math.floor(math.log2(num)) + 1 if num >= (1 << 32) else 32
    # Take those bits where there is a "one" in the number
    return [1 << p for p in range(num_bits) if num & (1 << p)]

print(two_powers(42))
# [2, 8, 32]
```

EDIT: Wrt the number of bits, you can make more splits if you are really concerned about performance, either down to save iterations or up to avoid computing the logarithm (or if you know your input numbers are going to be in some particular range):

```
import math

def two_powers(num):
    # Compute number of bits for big numbers
    if num < (1 << 8):
        num_bits = 8
    elif num < (1 << 16):
        num_bits = 16
    elif num < (1 << 24):
        num_bits = 24
    elif num < (1 << 32):
        num_bits = 32
    else:
        num_bits = math.floor(math.log2(num)) + 1
    # Take those bits where there is a "one" in the number
    return [1 << p for p in range(num_bits) if num & (1 << p)]

print(two_powers(42))
# [2, 8, 32]
```

Comment: why do you suppose minimum of 32 bits? it can be wasteful if the inputs are small.

Comment: @tsionyx Yes, I edited the answer. The initial solution was a compromise between simplicity and avoiding having to compute the logarithm always. To be honest there is probably very small performance difference between the two in the end anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good actually, with a slight (big!) detail  of efficiency:

Use

```
1<<i
```

(bitwise shift) instead of

```
2**i
```

So, to copy you, consider the following :

```
def two_powers(num):
    return set(1 << i for i, j in enumerate(bin(num)[-1: 1: -1]) if j == '1')
print two_powers(42)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `log2` and generator expression
until you are run out of powers of two.

```
import math

def two_powers(num):
    while num > 0:
        power = int(math.log(num, 2))
        yield 2**power
        num = num - 2**power
```

Sample run:

```
>>> tuple(two_powers(42)))
(32, 8, 2)
>>> tuple(two_powers(43)))
(32, 8, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Attn: Late Posters:** Please feel free to run this small benchmark
>   including your code, and amend the results accordingly. You will need
>   to re-run the tests for everyone as hardware differences will happen.

Gentlemen, here are your scores:

## The winner is @tsionyx

#### timeit:

```
Benchmark <=10^2
[97, 48, 31, 39, 33, 69, 71, 21, 50, 17]
two_powers_op_____ 17.8 µs ± 1.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_jdehesa 15.1 µs ± 888 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_matina_ 14.6 µs ± 755 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_agile_e 7.87 µs ± 524 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_taras__ 25.8 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_sunitha 12 µs ± 1.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_blhsing 11.5 µs ± 566 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_tsionyx 5.77 µs ± 57.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
Benchmark <=10^3
[682, 124, 42, 275, 743, 837, 474, 186, 739, 290]
two_powers_op_____ 22.1 µs ± 710 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_jdehesa 17.9 µs ± 829 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_matina_ 17.6 µs ± 881 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_agile_e 12.7 µs ± 763 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_taras__ 49.2 µs ± 3.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_sunitha 18.1 µs ± 2.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_blhsing 19.2 µs ± 2.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_tsionyx 10.4 µs ± 1.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
Benchmark <=10^4
[4641, 5675, 3355, 4746, 9948, 5192, 3446, 7174, 1683, 7611]
two_powers_op_____ 30.8 µs ± 3.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_jdehesa 22.2 µs ± 2.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_matina_ 21.7 µs ± 1.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_agile_e 17.5 µs ± 2.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_taras__ 64.3 µs ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_sunitha 18.5 µs ± 1.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_blhsing 19.2 µs ± 193 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_tsionyx 11.6 µs ± 43.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
Benchmark <=10^5
[20885, 23810, 25330, 32967, 34183, 16847, 54905, 85767, 37069, 32379]
two_powers_op_____ 32.8 µs ± 1.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_jdehesa 24.2 µs ± 534 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_matina_ 27.1 µs ± 2.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_agile_e 18.7 µs ± 246 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
two_powers_taras__ 68.9 µs ± 3.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_sunitha 20.6 µs ± 486 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_blhsing 22.7 µs ± 883 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_tsionyx 14.2 µs ± 244 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
Benchmark <=10^6
[182928, 93105, 710309, 926572, 859733, 818327, 654197, 829750, 358363, 946684]
two_powers_op_____ 40.6 µs ± 236 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_jdehesa 28.2 µs ± 310 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_matina_ 27.9 µs ± 936 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_agile_e 23.8 µs ± 364 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_taras__ 89.9 µs ± 406 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_sunitha 24.4 µs ± 493 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_blhsing 26.6 µs ± 366 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
two_powers_tsionyx 19.3 µs ± 95.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

#### code used:

```
import functools
import math
import random
from collections import defaultdict


def two_powers_op_____(num):
    return tuple(2 ** i for i, j in enumerate(bin(num)[-1: 1: -1]) if j == '1')


def two_powers_jdehesa(num):
    num_bits = math.floor(math.log2(num)) + 1
    return [1 << p for p in range(num_bits) if num & (1 << p)]


def two_powers_matina_(num):
    return set(1 << i for i, j in enumerate(bin(num)[-1: 1: -1]) if j == '1')


def two_powers_agile_e(num):
    powers = []
    while num != 0:
        powers.append(num & -num)
        num = num & (num - 1)
    return powers


def _two_powers_taras(num):
    while num > 0:
        power = int(math.log(num, 2))
        yield 2 ** power
        num = num - 2 ** power


def two_powers_taras__(num):
    return tuple(_two_powers_taras(num))


def two_powers_sunitha(num):
    return {1 << i for i, d in enumerate(reversed(bin(num)[2:])) if d == '1'}


def _two_powers_blhsing(n):
    m = 1
    while n >= m:
        if n & m:
            yield m
        m <<= 1


def two_powers_blhsing(n):
    return tuple(_two_powers_blhsing(n))


def two_powers_tsionyx(num):
    powers = []
    while num > 0:
        rest = num & (num - 1)
        powers.append(num - rest)
        num = rest

    return powers


funcs = [
    two_powers_op_____,
    two_powers_jdehesa,
    two_powers_matina_,
    two_powers_agile_e,
    two_powers_taras__,
    two_powers_sunitha,
    two_powers_blhsing,
    two_powers_tsionyx,
]


# ================== UTILITY FUNCTIONS ======================= #

def _partial_map(f, vals):
    """Run function on a range of inputs as a single function"""
    p = functools.partial(map, f, vals)
    p.__name__ = f.__name__
    return p


def _sanity_check(f, n):
    factors = f(n)
    assert len(factors) > 0
    # factors are unique
    assert len(set(factors)) == len(factors)
    assert sum(factors) == n

    for f in factors:
        b = bin(f)
        assert b == '0b1' + '0' * (len(b) - 3)


def benchmark(fs, inputs):
    for f in fs:
        for n in inputs:
            _sanity_check(f, n)

    aggr_funcs = [_partial_map(f, inputs) for f in fs]

    res = dict()
    print(inputs)
    for f in aggr_funcs:
        print(f.__name__, end=' ')
        tres = %timeit -o tuple(f())
        res[f.__name__] = tres.average

    return res


def plot(results):
    %matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18})

    leg = []
    for k, v in results.items():
        x, y = zip(*sorted(v.items()))
        plt.plot(x, [i * 10 ** 6 for i in y])
        leg.append(k)

    plt.legend(leg, loc='upper left')
    plt.ylabel('μs')
    plt.show()


full_res = defaultdict(dict)
for degree in range(2, 7):
    print('Benchmark <=10^%i' % degree)
    for name, t in benchmark(funcs, [random.randint(1, 10 ** degree) for _ in range(10)]).items():
        full_res[name][degree] = t

# you can view the results if you run it inside a jupyter notebook
# just uncomment the following line
# plot(full_res)
```

measured on Lenovo ThinkPad E480

Comment: Thank you! I have already started to make a similar benchmark script when noticed your answer. Maybe you should try it on a set of input values?

Comment: You should edit my post and remove your entry @sunitha

Comment: Go ahead, you can edit my post, as long as you make sure you don't break the code, and that the next poster can still use it. It is all yours to play with.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I get syntax error on this line: `%timeit(func(num))`

Comment: Do you mean the last edit? I changed the function from returning generator to returning a list, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51859187/revisions

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> n=42
>>> {1<<i for i,d in enumerate(reversed(bin(n)[2:])) if d=='1'}
{8, 2, 32}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator with a shifting bit mask:

```
def two_powers(n):
    m = 1
    while n >= m:
        if n & m:
            yield m
        m <<= 1
```

So that:

```
tuple(two_powers(42))
```

would be:

```
(2, 8, 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Agile_Eagle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51786517/1177288)

```
def two_powers(num):
    powers = []
    while num > 0:
        rest = num & (num - 1)
        powers.append(num - rest)
        num = rest

    return powers
```